# Scaling Stateful NodeJS Services - Stickiness/Affinity Based on Object ID (not user session)

Tags: node.js, scale, stateful

I am trying to find a good way to horizontally scale a stateful NodeJS service.

**The Problem**

The problem is that most of the options I find online assume the service is stateless. The NodeJS cluster documentation says:

> Node.js [Cluster] does not provide routing logic. It is, therefore important to design an application such that it does not rely too heavily on in-memory data objects for things like sessions and login.
>   https://nodejs.org/api/cluster.html

We are using Kubernetes so scaling across multiple machines would also be easy if my service was stateless, but it is not.

**Current Setup**

I have a list of objects that stay in memory, each object alone is a transaction boundary. Requests to this service always have the object ID in the url. Requests to the same object ID are put into a queue and processed one at a time.

**Desired Setup**

I would like to keep this interface to the external world but internally spread this list of objects across multiple nodes and based on the ID in the URL the request would be routed to the appropriate node.

[image: routing request to appropriate node based on ID in URL]

What is the usual way to do it in NodeJS? I've seen people using the user session to make sure a given user always go to the same node, what I would like to do is the same thing but instead of using the user session using the ID in the url.